# Nginx subdomain to subdomain redirect not working

Tags: nginx, redirect

The config below redirects to `.another-domain.com` with empty subdomain name. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
  server_name ~^(\w+)\.domain\.com$;
  location / {
    rewrite ^ $scheme://$1.another-domain.com$request_uri permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Without context one guess: If that is the only or first server block, it may implicitly be the default server block, which gets used for all requests, regardless if they match the `server_name` pattern or not. Simply create an additional and separate server block to become the default server and/or a server for the bare domain to ensure it gets handled properly and/or this server block won't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NGINX docs [mention](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) that for the `server_name` directive:

> the digital references can easily be overwritten

Thus you should use named captures.

Also, since you're performing site-wide redirect without complicated URL substitutions, you can simply use `return` directly in the `server` context:

```
server {
  server_name ~^?(?<subdomain>\w+)\.domain\.com$;
  return 301 $scheme://$subdomain.another-domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Also, as per comment above, make sure this isn't the default server in your NGINX configuration. You can do that by simply supplying `default_server` flag in the other `server`'s `listen` directive.

Comment: I found out that it's just `(\w)` doesn't work, named variables like `(?<subdomain>\w+)` are working properly. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vladimir basic regex stuff. `(\w)` will match only one character while `(\w+)` will match one or more. I highly suggest using regex101.com for checking your regexes. Invaluable resource :)

Comment: I mean `(\w+)` ofcourse, just a type mistake

Comment: Hm, see my note where I cite nginx docs `the digital references can easily be overwritten`. I think this is exactly what is happening, thus named captures are better suited overall.